# Devspace tool. How to deploy dependeny in --force-build mode

Tags: azure-devops, devops, devspace

I use DevSpace tool to deploy my services into minikube local cluster.

I have two services to deploy: ***auth-handler*** and ***mysql***;

auth-handler has the dependency of my-sql in devspace.xml. So it can't start till mysql hasn't been deployed.

***auth-handler***

```
dependencies:
  - source:
      path: ../mysql
    namespace: databases
```

mysql has the image stage. Where in Dockerfile I perform logic to initiate DB by some data.

```
images:
  backend:
    image: registry.kube-system.svc.cluster.local/mysql
    tags:
      - local
    dockerfile: ./mysql/Dockerfile
```

The first time, it works fine. But for example when I redeploy services the second time ***mysql*** image stage for ***mysql*** is skipped because DevSpace caches the image stage if it's already been successfully built. So my DB isn't initialized at this time because image stage skipped.

I can manually deploy ***mysql*** with `-b / --force-build`to deploy mysql with the forcing launching of image stage but I don't need to manually deploy ***mysql***. I need to initiate deployment of ***auth-handler*** and it will initiate deploying ***mysql*** in ``` -b / --force-build``-b / --force-build ``` mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of populating your database within the Dockerfile, I would recommend adding a hook in the `hooks` section of devspace.yaml which could run `devspace enter -c [mysql] -- command-to-populate-db` or alternatively, adding an init container to populate the database. This will be a lot more flexible.

For more details on hooks, have a look at the DevSpace docs: https://devspace.sh/cli/docs/configuration/hooks/basics